# Parallel methods do not run as expected

Tags: selenium, webdriver, testng

I need all the tests to be part of single class and run these tests in parallel. I'm using parallel="methods" in Testng.xml. I have class like

```
 Public class DemoParallel{
@Test
/* some code to launch Google.*/
@Test
 /* some code to launch Facebook*/
 }
```

Actual : 2 instances of chrome launches. Google test is running completely.Facebook test is only launched but does not run. Gets hanged. Only one test passes and also have tried implementing listeners but no luck.
Any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: Add the *some code to launch* and the Testng.xml

Comment: It seems you are using `static` while creating webdriver instance

Comment: No have not used static for driver instance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Local Driver Factory :**

```
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver;

class LocalDriverFactory {
    static WebDriver createInstance(String browserName) {
        WebDriver driver = null;
        if (browserName.toLowerCase().contains("firefox")) {
            System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.marionette","path to driver exe");
            driver = new FirefoxDriver();
            return driver;
        }
        if (browserName.toLowerCase().contains("internet")) {
            driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
            return driver;
        }
        if (browserName.toLowerCase().contains("chrome")) {
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","path to driver exe");
            driver = new ChromeDriver();
            return driver;
        }
        return driver;
    }
}
```

**use ThreadLocal class as follows :**

```
public class LocalDriverManager {
    private static ThreadLocal<WebDriver> webDriver = new ThreadLocal<WebDriver>();

    public static WebDriver getDriver() {
        return webDriver.get();
    }

    static void setWebDriver(WebDriver driver) {
        webDriver.set(driver);
    }
}
```

**Create Webdriver Listener class :**

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.testng.IInvokedMethod;
import org.testng.IInvokedMethodListener;
import org.testng.ITestResult;

 public class WebDriverListener implements IInvokedMethodListener {
@Override
public void beforeInvocation(IInvokedMethod method, ITestResult testResult) {
    if (method.isTestMethod()) {
        String browserName = method.getTestMethod().getXmlTest().getLocalParameters().get("browserName");
        WebDriver driver = LocalDriverFactory.createInstance(browserName);
        LocalDriverManager.setWebDriver(driver);
    }
}

@Override
public void afterInvocation(IInvokedMethod method, ITestResult testResult) {
    if (method.isTestMethod()) {
        WebDriver driver = LocalDriverManager.getDriver();
        if (driver != null) {
            driver.quit();
        }
    }
}
```

}

**Test Class**

```
public class ThreadLocalDemo {
    @Test
    public void testMethod1() {
        invokeBrowser("https://www.google.com/");
    }

    @Test
    public void testMethod2() {
        invokeBrowser("http://www.facebook.com");

    }

    private void invokeBrowser(String url) {
        System.out.println("Thread id = " + Thread.currentThread().getId());
        System.out.println("Hashcode of webDriver instance = " + LocalDriverManager.getDriver().hashCode());
        LocalDriverManager.getDriver().get(url);

    }
}
```

**Suite Xml File :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite" parallel="methods">
<listeners>
<listener class-name="path-to-class-WebDriverListener"></listener>
</listeners>
    <test name="Test">
        <parameter name="browserName" value="firefox"></parameter>
        <classes>
            <class name="path-to-class-ThreadLocalDemo" />
        </classes>
    </test> <!-- Test -->
</suite> <!-- Suite -->
```